# SqlGeography.STPolyFromText - Throws Error 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees

Tags: c#, sql, geojson, sqlgeography

when I am converting polygon text to sqlGeography object I get error "**24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.**"
Polygon example which throws error:

```
  POLYGON((58.197682 -151.896133,58.26688 -151.839327,58.256878 -151.79607,58.186908 -151.807954,58.165101 -151.863333,58.197682 -151.896133))
```

[image]
There is realated question but no answer for it:
[DbGeography's FromText throwing error in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713686/dbgeographys-fromtext-throwing-error-in-c-sharp)

I though it can convert fine and "MakeValid()" is fixing it - and in some previous cases it did work.
I got "US States" GEOJSON from this page: https://exploratory.io/map

**How to fix that conversion to sqlGeography was handled successfully?**

Comment: Also there is "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702423/invalid-latitude-value-must-be-between-90-and-90" realated answer.

But swamping lat/long places did not help - as they are correct now. If I swam - polygons would get in different place than expected.

Comment: Some other wiki related to question: https://danielwertheim.se/sqlgeography-in-sql-server-2012-polygon-must-start-on-correct-position/

Comment: I know this is a somewhat older question but you refer to swapping lat/long as being wrong when it is in fact absolutely correct. In text strings when working with the geography types, the coordinates are `X Y`. This makes geometry/geography coordinates both work the same way but means that it's `Long Lat`, which is the opposite of the usual convention. Swapping is the right thing to do, and means that you polygons *actually end up in the right place*. Your polygons are currently *consistently wrong*.